# Replace part of a formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a formula that I run within a Google sheet.
The formula extracts data from a database and it is segmented by the name of the business.
The formula is:

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j-2QkMRB8VG5YumBh0nZ_fbwoQW87xxJ4wz2NZqd8s4/edit#gid=1504008710","Log for Print!A:E"), "select * where Col3 = 'ABC Shop - Sydney'")
```

To extract the data for Music Shop - London, the user has to change the formula each time.

Is it possible to build a button that refers to a cell where the operator enters the name of the business and this replaces the text?

[image]

Then, the macro opens this data in a new sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j-2QkMRB8VG5YumBh0nZ_fbwoQW87xxJ4wz2NZqd8s4/edit#gid=1504008710","Log for Print!A:E"), "select * where Col3 = '"&B1&"' ")
```

instead of button, you can build a drop-down list in B1 with

```
=unique(query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j-2QkMRB8VG5YumBh0nZ_fbwoQW87xxJ4wz2NZqd8s4/edit#gid=1504008710","Log for Print!A:E"), "select Col3 "))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ycrVMCUtbtlR_VCWwg3fy2LL4gNKO-m1yCF1RlgHdeA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sincere thanks I will play around with this variation